# xamarin,let label react to <strong> or <b>

Tags: xamarin

i have a xamarin label and I fill it up with this text:

**Hier haben wir einen fettten Text!**
HIER NICHT MEHR

And I want the first part of the label to be bold and tthe second part no longer.

I set my label to this: `<Label TextColor="{StaticResource TextBlack}" TextType="Html" x:Name="label_description"/>`

SO it whould accept the tags.
But it just ignors them.

My feeling is, that it is because i dont have "strong" or "bold" font for it to use.
How would I achieve that?

Best,

J

Comment: If you set the label text in code behind, there are some differences. ```&lt;``` in XAML should be ```<``` in code behind, ```&quot;``` in XAML should be ```\"``` in code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the label to display HTML text. Here is the code to make the the first part of the label to be bold and the second part no longer.

```
 <Label Text="&lt;strong &gt;Hier haben wir einen fettten Text! &lt;/strong&gt; HIER NICHT MEHR."
        TextType="Html"  />
```

More information about how to [display HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html) in a label.

In addition, you can also use the `Span` to display it.

```
<Label FontSize="16">
   <Label.FormattedText>
       <FormattedString>
          <FormattedString.Spans>
             <Span Text="first part of the label " FontAttributes="Bold"/>
             <Span Text="Second part of the label"/>
           </FormattedString.Spans>
       </FormattedString>
   </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: again i already set it to what u said but it just ignores bold font. I beleive maybe there is a bold font type missing. how would I set that?

Comment: I changed the code and you can refer to it. Both of the methods are working well.

Comment: Span would be the better approach for this.